# Voltage calculation for the schematic

Tags: voltage, calculus

I would like to know how to calculate the output voltage for the following schematic.

I would also like to see the calculations step by step. Right now I am not able to do this, I'm kind of new in the electronics area and will take me a lot of time to figure out the output voltage.

Here is the schematic:

[image: Schematic]

I am interested in the value on inverted and non-inverted inputs of op-amp, the value of U<sub>e</sub> and the value of U<sub>s</sub>.

Comment: FWIW, there's also a proof sketch at http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-howland.html And in many textbooks dealing with opamps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a summary of the modified/improved Howland current source from [this](http://michaelgellis.tripod.com/howland.html) site

[image]

I tried to compress it for fitting in the space but it is a little hard to read so, if you right-click and save you can open it in your favourite viewer.

Take note that the important things to consider are R2 and R4 are equal in the OP's question and ditto R1 and R3.